# How to make sure fs.createWriteStream finishes before function continues; only fraction of image being saved

Tags: javascript, mongodb, express, fs

I am making a request to an API to get a path to an image. I want to save this image to my database in a mongoDB collection so that the users don't need to constantly make API requests.

I have something set up where I make a request to the imagePath and with the response, I pipe fs.createWriteStream().

Then later on in the code, I use my schema to create a "Character" using this file. It works, but it only saves a fraction of the image, like a top 1/5th. It's not finishing before it continues.

I tried making the function async and then using await before my url request. I have also tried various express/fs methods, like writeFileSync() but those haven't worked.

How do I get the file to finish writing before it does the mongoDB dance?

```
 let imagePath = req.body.characterObject.thumbnail.path + '.' + req.body.characterObject.thumbnail.extension;

 let superPath = './uploads/marvelousImage.jpg';
let marvelousImage;
  axios({
      url: imagePath,
      responseType: 'stream',
  })
  .then(response => {
      marvelousImage = response.data.pipe(fs.createWriteStream(superPath));

  })
  .catch(err => {
      console.log(err)
  });

    User.findOne({  "username": "administrator"})
    .then(user => {
      let characterId = req.body.characterObject.id;
      for(let i = 0; i < user.characters.length; i++) {
        if(characterId == user.characters[i].id) {
          return Promise.reject({
            code: 422,
            message: 'You already have this character!',
            reason: "CharacterDuplicationError"
          });
        }
      }
      console.log(req.body.characterObject);
      Character.create({
          description: req.body.characterObject.description || 'bocho',
          events: req.body.characterObject.events || 'lopo',
          thumbnail: req.body.characterObject.thumbnail || 'goso',
          name: req.body.characterObject.name || 'John Doe',
          id: req.body.characterObject.id,
          "image.data": fs.readFileSync(superPath),
          "image.contentType": 'image/jpeg'
      })
      .then(char => {
          console.log('lalala');
          console.log(char);
        user.characters.push(char);
        user.save();
        return res.status(201).json({message: "Character Added!"})
      })
    .catch(err => {
        if(err.reason === "CharacterDuplicationError") {
          return res.send(err);
        } 
    })
   })
 });
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It isn't clear that this is your only issue here, but it is one of the issues.

In this code:

```
  .then(response => {
      marvelousImage = response.data.pipe(fs.createWriteStream(superPath));

  })
```

The promise chain is not waiting for the pipe to finish reading/writing.  To do that, you need to return a promise from that `.then()` handler that resolves when the reading/writing is done.  You can do that by listening to events on the writeStream.  `.pipe()` returns the write stream so we can use that return value to set up event handlers and then use those events to resolve/reject a promise that we return.  This will make the promise chain wait for the streaming to finish before going to the next `.then()` in the promise chain.

```
 .then(response => {
     return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
         marvelousImage = response.data.pipe(fs.createWriteStream(superPath));
         marvelousImage.on('error', reject).on('close', resolve);
     });
  });
```

---

Then, I immediately see that you start your database stuff outside of the promise chain.  That has to be inside the promise chain.

I attempted to put everything into the promise chain here and flatten the chain and clean up your error handling:

```
let imagePath = req.body.characterObject.thumbnail.path + '.' + req.body.characterObject.thumbnail.extension;
let superPath = './uploads/marvelousImage.jpg';

axios({
    url: imagePath,
    responseType: 'stream'
}).then(response => {
     return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
         let marvelousImage = response.data.pipe(fs.createWriteStream(superPath));
         marvelousImage.on('error', reject).on('close', resolve);
     });
}).then(() => {
    return User.findOne({"username": "administrator"});
}).then(user => {
    let characterId = req.body.characterObject.id;
    for (let i = 0; i < user.characters.length; i++) {
        if (characterId == user.characters[i].id) {
            return Promise.reject({
                code: 422,
                message: 'You already have this character!',
                reason: "CharacterDuplicationError"
            });
        }
    }
    console.log(req.body.characterObject);
    return Character.create({
        description: req.body.characterObject.description || 'bocho',
        events: req.body.characterObject.events || 'lopo',
        thumbnail: req.body.characterObject.thumbnail || 'goso',
        name: req.body.characterObject.name || 'John Doe',
        id: req.body.characterObject.id,
        "image.data": fs.readFileSync(superPath),
        "image.contentType": 'image/jpeg'
    });
}).then(char => {
    console.log('lalala');
    console.log(char);
    user.characters.push(char);
    user.save();
    return res.status(201).json({
        message: "Character Added!"
    })
}).catch(err => {
    console.log(err);
    if (err.reason === "CharacterDuplicationError") {
        res.send(err);
    } else {
        res.sendStatus(500);
    }
});
```

Comment: What a great answer! It was helpful, educational, not at all condescending and helped me understand promises better.  You rock. Thanks!

Comment: Regards, @jfriend00 Additionally, an async function can use it.